# Unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator""

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create an array with inside: `1_0R 1_5R 2_0R`

```
char height[] = { 1_0R , 1_5R , 2_0R };
```

because I'm working with i/o files, and the string mentioned are inside the filenames. I use

```
+to_string( height[1] )+
```

When I compile I get the 3 errors

```
 **error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator""_0R’**
 **error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator""_5R’**
 **error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator""_0R’**
```

What can I do?

Comment: do you mean `char *height[] = { "1_0R" , "1_5R" , "2_0R" }`?

Comment: when he says "numeric literal" I assumed he meant a "user defined literal" of R as in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot name variables using digits at the beginning.

Those variables are not accepted by C++ naming variable criteria.

I guess you mean the following

```
char *height[] = {"1_0R","1_5R","2_0R"}
```